# Ionic Grid - row not taking up full width

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a simple grid, currently with one row and seven columns. Each column consists of a div containing one letter of text. I want these columns to space evenly out across the page, as is meant to be the default behaviour, but they are all bunched up on the left. Setting the row's width to 100% with an id doesn't help. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="column positive-bg stable" ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">M</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `col` instead `column` class.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col positive-bg stable" ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">M</div>
</div>
```

[More about Ionic Grid](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid).

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thanks!